# Implementing a Tax Feature in an ERC20 token

Tags: solidity

Good day Everyone, I am trying to implement a tax feature in an ERC20 token.
I successfully implemented something similar to a project that involved the creation of a TRC20 token using the code below as a reference:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
contract TransfertTokenAndPercentageToTargetAddress{

// pay 1% of all transactions to target address
address payable target = TUEtmARJ2m147RDJ5hy37mhZhEqx2Fnv8r; // I converted the tron address, I didn't use it as shown 

// state variables for your token to track balances and to test
mapping (address => uint) public balanceOf;
uint public totalSupply;

// create a token and assign all the tokens to the creator to test
constructor(uint _totalSupply) public {
    totalSupply = _totalSupply;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
}

// the token transfer function with the addition of a 1% share that
// goes to the target address specified above
function transfer(address _to, uint amount) public {

    // calculate the share of tokens for your target address
    uint shareForX = amount/100;

    // save the previous balance of the sender for later assertion
    // verify that all works as intended
    uint senderBalance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    
    // check the sender actually has enough tokens to transfer with function 
    // modifier
    require(senderBalance >= amount, 'Not enough balance');
    
    // reduce senders balance first to prevent the sender from sending more 
    // than he owns by submitting multiple transactions
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
    
    // store the previous balance of the receiver for later assertion
    // verify that all works as intended
    uint receiverBalance = balanceOf[_to];

    // add the amount of tokens to the receiver but deduct the share for the
    // target address
    balanceOf[_to] += amount-shareForX;
    
    // add the share to the target address
    balanceOf[target] += shareForX;

    // check that everything works as intended, specifically checking that
    // the sum of tokens in all accounts is the same before and after
    // the transaction. 
    assert(balanceOf[msg.sender] + balanceOf[_to] + shareForX ==
        senderBalance + receiverBalance);
   }

}
```

Then I tried to follow the same approach for an ERC20 token using the template from openzeppelin: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20

The following code shows the result of the modification:

```
function _transfer(

address from,
address to,
uint256 amount
) internal virtual {

require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");

require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

_beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

uint tax = amount/10;


uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];

require(fromBalance >= amount + tax, "ERC20: transfer amount and Tax exceeds balance");
unchecked {
    _balances[from] = fromBalance - amount - tax;
}

uint receiverBalance = _balances[to];

_balances[to] += amount;

_balances[target] += tax;

emit Transfer(from, to, amount);

_afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

// assert(_balances[from] + _balances[to] + tax == fromBalance + receiverBalance);
}
```

The token was successfully minted but the transfer function won't work. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the description with the revert message? Your implementation of `transfer(address, address,uint256)` can fail for a couple reasons: (most obviously) `target` is not defined.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I had fixed the issue the while back. I can't remember what I modified but it wasn't the code above.